# java swing addTaskListener

Tags: java, swing, data-binding, javabeans

I am new to java and have a swing task question.

Can I add a listener to a currently running task?  For instance if something happens in doInBackGround I want to add a listener for finished and display a dialog.  I have tried but the compiler doesnt like me. :)

Something like.

```
private class MyTask extends Task<Void, Void>{
  @Override
  public void doInBackground(){
     if(foo == foo){
        this.addTaskListener(new TaskListener() {
          public void taskFinsished(){}...
         });
     }
  }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: why don't you add it to MyTask's constructor ?

Answer (score 2):

Task is not a listener-oriented component. You need to override one or more of it's methods to get the results. All of these methods will execute on the EDT.

**cancelled()** - The `cancel()` method was called to terminate the task.

**succeeded(T result)** - The `Task` completed, and `result` holds the return value from `doInBackground()`.

**interrupted(InterruptedException e)** - `interrupt` was called on the `Thread` executing the `Task`.

**failed(Throwable cause)** - The `doInBackground` threw an exception.

**finished()** - The `Task` has finished (in some fashion). Think of this as the functional equivalent of `finally` for `Tasks`.